Matrix plot with tally marks using ggplot
I'm trying to make a matrix plot like this without the dendrogram to represent meta data (specifically adding the top part with the group, grade, simpson, and age info).
enter image description here
I can plot a basic matrix plot (like the lower part of the plot)

Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please take the tour, read How to ask a good question and Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example and How to make a great R reproducible example. Include data and the code you have tried in the question, please.
